# Proving the global characterization of graphs in smooth manifolds. An immersed submanifold is a graph of a smooth map.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

this is part of Theorem 6.32 (Global Characterization of Graphs) in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $S \subset M \times N$ is an immersed submanifold. Let $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$ be the projections from $M \times N $ onto $M$ and $N$ , respectively. The following are equivalent.
(a) $S$ is the graph of a smooth map $f: M \to N$. (b) $\pi_M|_S$ is a diffeomorphism from $S$ onto $M$.

Proving $(b) \to (a)$ can be done by defining $f= \pi_N \circ (\pi_M|_S)^{-1}$. But I am not sure how to prove $(a)\to (b)$. The obvious way seems to be if we have $S=\{(x,f(x)):x\in M\}$ for a smooth map $f:M \to N$, then since $\pi_M|_S$ is a smooth map we just need to find a smooth inverse. And the natural candidate would be the map $g:M \to S$ defined by $g(x)=(x,f(x))$. However, I cannot prove that $g$ is smooth. The problem here is that $S$ is an immersed submanifold and not an embedded submanifold. So I cannot simply think of $g$ as a map into $M\times N$ and restrict the codomain because restricting the codomain of a smooth map requires continuity of the map $g$ as a map from $M$ into $S$ (Theorem 5.29) and this I cannot guarantee from the given assumptions. How can I prove this part? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you try and prove that $f: M \to N$ is locally an embedding? Certainly it is injective, and a continuous injection on a compact subset is a homeomorphism on to its image.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon What do you mean here? $f$ is only assumed to be a smooth map.

Comment: @SumantaDas I know we have to use the two theorems. But how do we know that $g$ is continuous as a function into $S$? That is my question.

Comment: @SumantaDas So define $h:M \to M\times N$ as $h(m)=(m,f(m))$ and $g$ as $h$ with the restriction of the codomain to $S$. Then for $m\in M$, $(m,f(m))\in S$ and we can find an open subset $U$ of $M\times N$ such that $(m,f(m))\in U \cap S$. Since $h^{-1}(U\cap S) = h^{-1}(U)$, and since $h$ is smooth as a map into $M \times N$, $h^{-1}(U\cap S)$ is an open neighborhood of $m$, but $h^{-1}(U \cap S) = g^{-1}(U \cap S)$, so $g$ is continuous at $m$. Since $m$ is arbitrary, $g$ is continuous. Is this correct?

Comment: @SumantaDas What do you mean find all the small open subsets? So I actually need to show that for any open set containing $(m,f(m))$ the inverse of $g$ will be open in $M$, but the locally embedded theorem only gives me a particular neighborhood that is an embedded submanifold of $M\times N$. How do I show this for all neighborhoods?

Comment: @SumantaDas I don't think I understand what you mean. So the local embedding theorem only gives us a small open subset in which $(m,f(m))$ belongs to and is an embedded submanifold of $M \times N$. So the inverse image of this open subset will be open containing $m$ in $M$, but continuity requires that the inverse images of all open sets in $S$ containing $(m,f(m))$ are open in $M$. So how do we prove this using the local embedding theorem?

Comment: @SumantaDas But we are not dealing with metric spaces here.

Comment: @SumantaDas Local Embedding Theorem gives us that there is an open subset $U$ of $(m,f(m))$ in $S$ that is an embedded submanifold of $M\times N$. Why does this mean that we would have an open set $W$ of $M \times N$ for which $U = W \cap S$?

Comment: @SumantaDas And assuming by $W_b$ you mean what I have written $U$ here, for any neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $(m,f(m))$ in $S$, we have $g^{-1}(V) = h^{-1}(V \cap U) = h^{-1}(V \cap W \cap S) = h^{-1}(V \cap W)$. But $V$ may not be an open set in $M \times N$, so we can't conclude from the continuity of $h: M \to M\times N$ that $h^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M$. I think this argument is more complicated than what you implied. I don't think a simple local embedding argument works here...

Comment: @nomadicmathematician: If $S$ is a graph of a smooth map then $S$ is actually embedded (Proposition 5.4) so there's no problem restricting the codomain of your map. I guess that by "$S$ is a graph of a smooth map $f$" is implicitly implied that the given topology and smooth structure on $S$ coincides with the standard (subspace) topology and smooth structure on the graph of $f$.

Comment: Hint: Every graph of a smooth map is an embedded submanifold. See Proposition 5.4 in ISM.

Comment: To prove (c) -> (a) or (b), do we not have to assume $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M\times N$? At this point in the book we have not defined transverse intersections for immersed manifolds yet.